# how to fix subscribeOn (io.reactivex.Schedular) in Flowable cannot be applied to (rx.scheduler)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to do Room database operations using Rx java Flowable, but I think there is an issue with my imports but not sure what is the actual problem.

Error I get is

[image]

UserDao

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAllUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>

    @Insert
    fun insertUser(user: User): Long
}
```

Presenter - where I am trying to access database is

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;

private void testingRoomDatabase() {
        com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User user = new com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User(
                1, "Test", "Room");
        Long abcd = userDao.insertUser(user);
        Flowable<List<com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User>> users = userDao.getAllUsers();

        getUsers().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // ***ISSUE IS HERE***
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(usersx -> {

        });
    }

    private Long addUser(com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User user) {
        return userDao.insertUser(user);
    }

    private Flowable<List<com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User>> getUsers () {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }
```

Gradle imports

```
// RxAndroid and RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.10'
implementation('com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

Your help is much appreciated

R

Comment: Try this import "import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers"

Comment: According to gradle spec, you are using 2 different versions of `rxjava`: 1.1.10 and 2.0.1 - each one have practically the same class names, located in different packages. First of all, don't mix up 2 different library versions until you have to.

Comment: Hello @P.Leibner and @ConstOrVar thank you for responding. Yes when I change the import to `import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;` that piece of code works fine. but in the same file I am using `protected CompositeSubscription subscriptions;` where I get simillar error, compositeSubscription is not part of rcjava2 right?

Comment: Your import comes for `RxJava1`. And `CompositeSubcription` is replaced with `CompositeDisposable`.